Is it possible to get the github repo link associated with git tree-sha1?
I wanted to get the github repo link. But all I have is repo url and git-tree-sha1.
I know how to get commit details from it and then create a link for the repo. But this requires me to clone that particular repo. How do I achieve this when I am not inside that repo, but trying to perform this somewhere else.

I am unclear exactly what you're looking for. GitHub doesn't support links to git trees; only to commits.

@larsks What I mean is that a git-tree-sha1 is generated for a particular commit. Now using that sha, how do I get the link for that commit.
